# Передача переменных в другой файл

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется файл script.php в нём определенный код на выборку с бд и добавление полученных данный в массив, но для примере я возьму лишь переменную, так как сути не меняет.
script.php:

```
  <?php
      $a = "Слово";
  ?>
```

Далее файл index.php который прикручивает ajax к script.php и в реальном времени получает данные с файла script.php, но дело в том что я хочу в index php выводить переменную $а но она не выводится. Почему?

index.php:

```
<script>
    function show()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "script.php",
            cache: false, 
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        show();
        setInterval('show()',1000);
    });
</script>

<?php
    echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы передать переменную в другой файл, вам не нужен ajax. Достаточно `include script.php; echo $a;`

Comment: ajax нужен не для передачи, а для обновления данных в script.php и последующим выводом уже конкретно обновленных данных))

Answer (score 2):

Файл `script.php`

```
<?php
      $a = ["Крутая структура данных"];
      echo json_encode($a);
```

Файл `index.php`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
           $.ajax({
               url: "script.php",
               cache: false, 
               success: function(html){
                   var content = JSON.parse(html);
                   // тут крутая функция вывода данных в $("#content")
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```